# Where the timestamps are added to the sensor data

Tags: android, timestamp, sensors

I would like to know, where the timestamps are added to the sensor data (Sensor IC?, at reception in the MCU?)? What is the reference time (Sensor IC clock?, MCU clock?).

Best regards

Ron

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is added to the sensor data at the structure sensors_event_t which can be found in the file 
[sensors.h](https://source.android.com/devices/halref/sensors_8h_source.html) at the HAL level from Sensor IC,reference clock being Sensor IC clock.

You can log and check the timestamps for distinguition through functions SensorEvent [event.timestamp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#timestamp) and SystemClock [getRealTimeElapsedNanos.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtimeNanos())